# Pandas MultiIndex Dataframe Styling error when writing to Excel

Tags: pandas, multi-index, pandas-styles

I am trying to write a multi-index data frame to excel using pandas styling and I am getting an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(9,4), pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B','C'], ['r1', 'r2','r3']]), columns=[['E1','E1','E2','E2'],['d1','d2','d1','d2']])

def highlight_max(s, props=''):
    return np.where(s == np.nanmax(s.values), props, '')

def highlight_all_by_condition (value, condition, props=''):
    return np.where(value >= condition, props, '')

def highlight_max_value_by_condition(value, condition, props=''):
    return np.where(np.nanmax(value) >= condition, props, '')

df_formatted = df.style.set_properties(**{'font-family': 'Arial','font-size': '10pt'})

unique_column_list = list(set(df.columns.get_level_values(0)))
idx = pd.IndexSlice
for each in unique_column_list:
    slice_=idx[idx[each]]
    df_formatted = df_formatted.apply(highlight_max, props='color:black; font-weight: bold', axis=1, subset=slice_)\
                               .apply(highlight_all_by_condition, condition = 0.55, props='color:red;font-weight: bold; background-color: #ffe6e6', axis=1, subset=slice_)\
                               .apply(highlight_max_value_by_condition, condition = 1, props='color:green;font-weight: bold; background-color: #ffff33', axis=1, subset=slice_)

df_formatted.to_excel("test.xlsx", engine = 'openpyxl')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Function <function highlight_max_value_by_condition at 0x000001EE1394E940> returned the wrong shape.
Result has shape: (9,)
Expected shape:   (9, 2)
```

The second styling function (highlight_max_value_by_condition) is a conditional styling, where it needs to highlight the max value only if it satisfies the condition and if I remove that styling function, then I don't get any error.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your composition. What are you trying to accomplish with `np.where(np.nanmax(value) >= condition, props, '')`? Currently you can produce at most a single value. Since `np.nanmax(value)` will give the largest value in the Series and that is either `>=` or not the condition. Meaning that you'll get a single props or a single empty string which is not the correct dimensions (as the error indicates)

Comment: Are you looking for _both_ the previous conditions to be true? `np.where((value == np.nanmax(value)) & (value >= condition), props, '')`?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have both conditions satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we're looking for `highlight_max_value_by_condition` is meant to apply styles to cells which are both the max in the subset and fulfill the condition we can add an `&` to combine the conditions:

```
def highlight_max_value_by_condition(value, condition, props=''):
    return np.where(
        (value == np.nanmax(value)) & (value >= condition),
        props,
        ''
    )
```

---

Beyond that, however, there are quite a few things we can do to cleanup the general approach.

`Styler` objects compound naturally, there is no need to assign back. In addition instead of using `list(set(` to get the level values, [MultiIndex.levels](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.levels.html) will already provide the unique values for each level. Furthermore, since we're working with the top-most level we don't need `pd.IndexSlice` since access column access by top-level MultiIndex key will provide all child columns.

All this together means that `df_formatted` can be build like:

```
df_formatted = df.style.set_properties(**{
    'font-family': 'Arial',
    'font-size': '10pt'
})

for slice_ in df.columns.levels[0]:
    df_formatted.apply(
        highlight_max,
        props='color:black; font-weight: bold',
        axis=1, subset=slice_
    ).apply(
        highlight_all_by_condition, condition=0.55,
        props='color:red;font-weight: bold; background-color: #ffe6e6',
        axis=1, subset=slice_
    ).apply(
        highlight_max_value_by_condition, condition=1,
        props='color:green;font-weight: bold; background-color: #ffff33',
        axis=1, subset=slice_
    )
```

[image: styled table]

---

Setup made reproducible with seed(6) and with modified function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(6)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(9, 4),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['r1', 'r2', 'r3']]),
    columns=[['E1', 'E1', 'E2', 'E2'], ['d1', 'd2', 'd1', 'd2']]
)


def highlight_max(s, props=''):
    return np.where(s == np.nanmax(s.values), props, '')


def highlight_all_by_condition(value, condition, props=''):
    return np.where(value >= condition, props, '')


def highlight_max_value_by_condition(value, condition, props=''):
    return np.where(
        (value == np.nanmax(value)) & (value >= condition),
        props,
        ''
    )
```

`df`:

```
            E1                  E2          
            d1        d2        d1        d2
A r1 -0.311784  0.729004  0.217821 -0.899092
  r2 -2.486781  0.913252  1.127064 -1.514093
  r3  1.639291 -0.429894  2.631281  0.601822
B r1 -0.335882  1.237738  0.111128  0.129151
  r2  0.076128 -0.155128  0.634225  0.810655
  r3  0.354809  1.812590 -1.356476 -0.463632
C r1  0.824654 -1.176431  1.564490  0.712705
  r2 -0.181007  0.534200 -0.586613 -1.481853
  r3  0.857248  0.943099  0.114441 -0.021957
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. When I tried to use df_formatted.to_excel, I am getting blank document with only headers written but no values. Is there something I need to do special when writing to excel?

Comment: Shouldn't be... `df_formatted.to_excel("test.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')` produced a styled sheet for me I'm using version 1.3.3 idk if that matters.

Comment: I am using the same pandas 1.3.3 version. I will check again. Maybe something to do with opepyxl. Thanks